# How can i debug Java classes remotely?

Tags: java, debugging

i am setting this as the JAVAWS_VM_ARGS:
-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y

to debug remotely. Everything works until i want to debug or step into Java classes, like java.lang.Class. And i have the sources attached... Does anyone know if i have to do something extra? In my Eclipse or in these arguments?

Thanks,
Teo

Comment: You don't have to do anything more than attaching the Java source code. Are you sure you've got the correct source code and that you've attached it correctly?

Comment: Yes, i believe so. I am on Java 1.6.0_19, i have only this JRE in my Eclipse settings and if i type CTRL+SHIFT+T and Class.class (this is what i care about, specifically the getResource method) i see a [jdk1.6.0_19] next to it. And then i can see the source (which i attached previously from the src.zip file inside the Java installation)

Comment: It doesn't go into the breakpoint, which i've put in getResource in Class.class. Also, i thought about steping into it from the calling method but stepping into it will just step over (and then i can't even read the returned value in my own code in the debugger).

Comment: Are you sure the code on the remote server was compiled with debugging enabled?

Comment: Hmm, no, but i am debugging the client. Should i remove this server=y thing?